# Typescript doesn't realize that all code paths return a value

Tags: typescript

How can I tell typescript that all possible code paths in a function return a value?

In my code, I pass in two numeric arrays, check that they are monotonically increasing, and then extract a value from the arrays based on some checks. From what I can tell there is no possible way to pass through this function without returning some defined value.

So my question is, do I have a bug here, and if not, is there a way to tell Typescript that all code paths (that do not throw) actually return a value?

```js
const monotonicIncreasing = (array: number[]) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i+1] < array[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// does not compile (all code paths must return a value)
const foo = (v1: number[], v2: number[], v: number) => {
    if (!v1.length || v1.length !== v2.length) {
        throw new Error("arrays must have same length");
    }

    if (!monotonicIncreasing(v1) || !monotonicIncreasing(v2)) {
        throw new Error("arrays must be monotonic increasing")
    }

    if (v <= v1[0]) {
        return v2[0];
    } else if (v > v1[v1.length-1]) {
        return v2[v2.length-1];
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < v1.length-1; i++) {
            if (v > v1[i]) {
                return v2[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

let a: number;

const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [3,4,5];

a = foo(arr1, arr2, 2);
```

Comment: Because it does not. Check the inside of your for loop.

Comment: @mamichels nope, the case of `v` being less than or equal to every item in `v1` is handled in the first clause of the `if else` and the restriction that the array must be sorted increasing ... but TS isn't smart enough to determine that

Comment: @mamichels `>` changing to `>=` did not help if that's what you refer to?

Comment: TS can not know that `v1` is orderd. You check this with `monotonicIncreasing` but TS does not know about the semantic of this function so it can not asume by the test `v <= v1[0]` that all elements of `v1` are less that `v`

Comment: @ackdari indeed, so considering this I would like to tell Typescript that I did check all potential code paths carefully, so that it will compile

Comment: After `if (v > v1[i]) {...}` add a `throw new Error(`Unexpected value for v: ${v}`)`

Comment: @ToivoSäwén I would recommend that you do what David said in his answer. If you are sure that all path are checked add `throw new Error("Something went wrong");` to the end and possibly a log call that you hopefully never see.

Answer (score 1):

TS isn't smart enough to figure out that you've handled the case of `v` being less than or equal to every item in `v1` with your first `if` clause and the restriction on the array being sorted increasing... you can rewrite it to be more explicit that this is the case so TS can figure it out...

```
if (v > v1[v1.length-1]) {
    return v2[v2.length-1];
} else {
    for (let i = 0; i < v1.length-1; i++) {
        if (v > v1[i]) {
            return v2[i];
        }
    }
    // if we get here, v <= v1[0]
    return v2[0];
}
```

Comment: Nice, this solves the particular issue but it would be useful to also have a way of telling the compiler that I checked all code paths and that they do in fact all return a value.

Comment: @David's answer is the way to do that. Throw an error at the end. But, I'd argue that it's better practice to make it explicit and definite that all code paths are covered if possible, you or another dev could accidentally break this in theory. I had to read through this to be sure, and the code is a bit obscure.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has a declared return type and must always return it. You can fix this problem by declaring a standard variable and then making sure that outside of all your if statements there's always a "default" `return`

```
const foo = (v1: number[], v2: number[], v: number) => {
    let var: number;
    if (!v1.length || v1.length !== v2.length) {
        throw new Error("arrays must have same length");
    }

    if (!monotonicIncreasing(v1) || !monotonicIncreasing(v2)) {
        throw new Error("arrays must be monotonic increasing")
    }

    if (v <= v1[0]) {
        var = v2[0];
    } else if (v > v1[v1.length-1]) {
        var = v2[v2.length-1];
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < v1.length-1; i++) {
            if (v > v1[i]) {
                var = v2[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return var;
}
```

Comment: this would make TS believe your return type is potentially undefined

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that TypeScript sees a logical path you (and I) don't.  Or, more likely, TypeScript isn't testing this code with possible values and, using a limited set of transpiling/compiling rules, it simply can't guarantee that all paths return a value.

Compilers/transpilers are generally more concerned with the structure and syntax than with the runtime logic.  Some are smart enough for basic logic (TypeScript can be pretty smart at times, such as when you have logic ensuring something isn't `undefined` before using it throughout the function), but it's not magic and won't test everything for you.

In cases like this, where you feel the very end of the function should *never* be reached, that's a good place to throw an error:

```
const foo = (v1: number[], v2: number[], v: number) => {
  // all of your current code, then...

  // perhaps also output/log the inputs to learn more about what happened?
  throw new Error("Something went wrong");
}
```

That way one of two things will happen:

1. The error will never be thrown, as expected by the developer
2. The error will someday be thrown, and you'll see useful information about the inputs to show you exactly what it was that you (and I) didn't see today